# angular2 animation callback change the value is not effect

Tags: angular, animation, callback

```
//animation
export const hiddenFade = trigger('hiddenFade', [
  transition('void => *', [
    animate('300ms', keyframes([
      style({opacity: 0}),
      style({opacity: 0.5}),
      style({opacity: 1}),
    ]))
  ]),
   transition('* => void', [
    animate('300ms 1s', keyframes([
      style({opacity: 1}),
      style({opacity: 0.5}),
      style({opacity: 0}),
    ]))
  ])
])

//component
isCheckForm: boolean = true;
```

//HTML

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isCheckForm" [@hiddenFade]  (@hiddenFade.done) = 'isCheckForm = true'>
  <label class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2  text-danger">{{showWarningText}}</label>
</div>
```

I want to effect is when the isCheckForm becomes false when doing void => * this animation after the end of this animation isCheckForm is true to do * => void animation slowly disappeared, but the animation did not disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HTML should be like below and i think `@hiddenFade.done` is not needed 
:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isCheckForm" [@hiddenFade]="isCheckForm" (@hiddenFade.done)="isCheckForm = true">
  <label class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2  text-danger">{{showWarningText}}</label>
</div>
```